# There is a scorch mark in the wall

Tags: water, heater

There is a scorch mark in  the wall where the pipe goes into from the hotwater heater. Should I be concerned

Comment: Probably just damage from a sweat joint. A pic seems like a necessity here.

Answer (score 2):

As long as nothing's smoking & there aren't any flames then, Nope. It's a typical sign of a propane like torch's use for copper plumbing & it could be from a long time ago. The plumber should've used a flame shield & you can clean it off if you'd like. Isopropyl Alcohol or just Swabs usually get rid of it pretty easily.